# Using VBA & IE I need to click a certain text on the page

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, controls

Here is the HTML I can see & partial of macro & Objective:

`<a class="Ligne0 OrderNo" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">20190180963865</a>`

```
    MsgBox IE.document.Url
    Dim element As IHTMLElement
    Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument

    Set HTML = IE.document

    Set elements = HTML.getElementsbyclassname("Ligne0 OrderNo")

    Dim Count As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    Dim BOO

    Count = 0

    For Each element In elements

        If element.classname = "Ligne0 OrderNo" Then

            erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            Cells(erow, 1) = HTML.getelementsbytagname("a")(Count).innertext

            BOO = HTML.getelementsbytagname("a")(Count).innertext

            Count = Count + 1

        End If

    Next element

    Range("A2:B11").Select
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 36

    MsgBox BOO

End Sub
```

The class Ligne0 OrderNO is unique in the body. I need to crosscheck "20190180963865" with an array I created and when found be able to click on element that takes me to another page.

What I have Tried:
** MSGBOX.ie.document.url gives me the correct URL. I cropped out the top of my macro here to save space.

MSGBOX BOO should give me "20190180963865" but instead gives me nothing. I added .innertext and .value but then the msgbox just doesnt show up.

then with the BOO I want to be able to .click the text on IE

** I have already checked off "references Microsoft internet control" and "Microsoft HTML object library"

Comment: If you are getting elements by class name and class for your element is unique on the page, your element collection should only every have one element in it. Why do you then need to get element by tag? you could just check the `innertext` and click on it

Answer (score 0):

You said that msgbox Boo is returning nothing. possible reason is that you are setting that variable in loop and you are fetching the value outside the loop. So it may be possible that when you try to fetch the value at that time it get replaced with empty value.

Based on your above code I develop this example which is looping through all the links on web page and match its inner text and class name and click the link.

VBA code:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    URL = "D:\Backup20190913\tests\295.html"

    IE.Navigate URL


    Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

    Set Alllinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")

    For Each Hyperlink In Alllinks
        If Hyperlink.innerText = "20190180963865" And Hyperlink.className = "Ligne0 OrderNo" Then
            Hyperlink.Click


        End If
    Next Hyperlink

    'Unload IE
    'Set IE = Nothing


End Sub
```

Sample HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function abc()
{
alert("clicked...");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="Ligne0 OrderNo" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;" onclick="abc()">20190180963865</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can modify your example as per your own requirement. you just need to fetch your values from the worksheet and match it in code above.

Let us know, if you have any difficulty for applying this suggestion.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to pull all elements on the page by tag name when class is unique?

Comment: This is just an example which loop though links and match it's innertext and class name. If op has no reason than op can definitely click the element directly with class name without loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop and the class is already for the `a` tag of interest so you don't want to then try selecting by tagName when already at the right level. querySelector returns a single node; the first node to match the specified selector - which in this case is the compound className for the element of interest (compound classes are joined by a "." and the "." represents a css class selector).

```
Dim BOO As String, element As Object

Set element = HTML.querySelector(".Ligne0.OrderNo")

If Not element Is Nothing Then
    BOO = element.innerText
    'do whatever else when element is found
End If
```